# What restrictions will my converted desktop app have in UWP

Tags: .net, uwp

We currently have a desktop app that does the following:

- We need to be able to use elevated permissions, for this part we use a Windows service running as a system account, to do things like set networking routes on the system.
- We need to be able to install a couple of kernel mode drivers.

We're looking at UWP, and wondering if any of this is going to be possible.

After looking through some articles, it looks to me like we would be possibly OK with a side-loaded app, but we'd be stuck if we wanted to do anything on the store.

Are any of the above features compatible with UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those features are not supported, as documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare

Comment: Do these restrictions apply equally to side-loaded apps?

Comment: It's a good question. Not all of them, but the Windows Service & Kernel Mode Drivers restrictions do apply also to side-loaded apps.